# react-select drop down choices not storing correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I'm using a [react-select](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) drop down to allow users to choose multiple options between A, B and C. Currently this works on the UI but when an option is de-selected, it is not removed from the array. Can anyone give me hints as to how this is done? (Example, A, B, and C are selected, then A is unselected, how can A be removed from the array?)

```js
var choice = [];
const choices = [
  { value: 'a', label: 'a' },
  { value: 'b', label: 'b' },
  { value: 'c', label: 'c' },
];          

handleChange = (selectedChoice) => {
  this.setState({ selectedChoice });
  for (var i = 0; i < selectedChoice.length; i++) {
    if (choice.indexOf(selectedChoice[i].value) == -1){
      choice.push(selectedChoice[i].value); 
    }
  }
}
```

Then, further down in the code `console.log(choice)` is called, printing when a button is clicked. Followed by:

```js
render(){
  return (
    <Div ClassName="box">
      <Select options={choices}
        isMulti
        value={this.state.selectedChoice}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
      />
    </Div>
  );
}
```

Push and pop won't work as the option could be in the middle.

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous, so you can't use `this.state` directly after setting it an expect that it has already updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need another choice variable.you already have `selectedChoice` state that will store all the selected value for you.

Working Solution: https://codesandbox.io/embed/0pr9yoo8l

Comment: That works if all I want to do is log the arrays they sit in (prints [[0 [value: a, label: a]] [1 [ value: b, label: b]]] But since value is held within a numbered array in selectedChoice, to get the actual values that have been chosen you need selectedChoice[0].value, which is why I have the for loop. Is there a way to get the values out of those arrays without doing that, as your code doesnt return anything or print out those values. (the point is to later on in the code only present results that match the the choices selected, EG, only results with an A tag)

Comment: @Uciebila you need to loop through the array using `array_map` method. I have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, had to move some stuff around to get it to fit with the handleClick button click etc, and remove the ' + ", "' from the output the return choice.value as this is set by the drop down itself, otherwise works!